# Headers not present in fetch() response

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get headers of response returned and consumed by react-native's `fetch()` method but it seems there is something not right with it and the headers aren't there.

I've seen that react-native team has accepted a PR with something probably related here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/fe42a28de12926c7b3254420ccb85bef5f46327f but i'm not sure if it targets the issue i'am currently facing. Anyway, i have installed a react-native from master (to have that recent PR applied) and my api endpoint retuns the following headers:

```
> curl --include 'http://192.168.0.111:3000/api/v1/items?limit=1'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Link: <http://192.168.0.111:3000/api/v1/items?limit=1&page=32>; rel="last", <http://192.168.0.111:3000/api/v1/items?limit=1&page=2>; rel="next"
Total: 32
Per-Page: 1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0

(...)
```

But, my fetch method can't see them for some reason:

```
fetch(CONFIG.api_url + '/items?limit=25').then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp.headers)
  console.log(resp.headers.getAll())
  console.log(resp.headers.get('Link'))
})
```

[image: fetch output]

Thanks in advance for any tips on how to access those headers (dirty hot-fixes welcome :)!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this from chrome fetch api (not using reactjs)and the documentation has no mention about this (even at the time of writing). I did some trail and errors and found the following works in chrome (checked this in version 47)

```
        //get all 'available' headers
        response.headers.forEach(function(value, key){
            console.log('[' + key + '] = '+value);

        });
```

Note that response headers are restricted based on the response type. See 'Response Types' section for more info https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en